# gmaps4rails in partial twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, gmaps4rails

I'm building a site where there is only one page and then a modal display. The modal shows various pages and has the core functionality of the app.  Each page in the modal is rendered via ajax so I have two problems I'm encountering

I need to render a map in a partial on the modal.  I've searched all over and no answer has solved the problem since the modal div itself exists from page load, but the partial does not.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The partial is loaded with ajax so the js dependencies included are not loaded.

You should add these manually in your source page.

To know which one are needed, display your modal and look at the html source.